# Iframe Loading image and IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, iframe

I'm loading an Iframe from an External server of mine onto my webpage, and I wanted a loading image, because sometimes it take a good 10 seconds to load. All is well in Chrome but in IE nothing.

```
<center>
<div style="background: #ffffff url(http://mentalized.net/activity-indicators/indicators/simon-claret/progress_bar.gif) no-repeat 50% 5%;">
<iframe src="http://x.x.x.x/panel.php" allowTransparency="true" width="100%" height="450px" scrolling="no"></iframe>
</div>
</center>
```

My other question is, is there a better way of doing this? I can't use ajax because it's an external server, but is there a better way of doing a loading image with an iFrame? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting the style with the background image information on the iframe itself, rather than the separate div.

```
<iframe src="http://x.x.x.x/panel.php" allowTransparency="true" width="100%" height="450px" scrolling="no" style="background: #ffffff url(http://mentalized.net/activity-indicators/indicators/simon-claret/progress_bar.gif) no-repeat 50% 5%;"></iframe>
```

Comment: Still works fine in Chrome, but it still doesnt even load the iFrame in IE, I just checked, and went to the panel.php in IE directly, and wow, It didn't even look right, I used this tutorial to make it http://gazpo.com/2011/02/form/ I assume since its CSS3 thats why it wont work in IE?

Comment: Perhaps I'm not following correctly... is your problem with getting the background image to appear, loading the panel.php in the iframe, or how the panel.php looks in IE? ...depending on what version of IE you're using, not all CSS3 styles will work in IE.

Comment: Using IE 8 and actually, All of the above lol, nothing is working right

Comment: Well, I tried out the iframe with the background style applied in IE8, pointing to a different iframe src of course, but the background image thing worked fine so I don't know what to tell you for that.  Regarding any details of the problems with your panel.php code, can't really address those without seeing the code.

Comment: Found it! I had no doctype, that fixed it all :)

Comment: Ah ha! Sometimes the basics are the easiest things to overlook. Glad you solved your problem. :)